# Bluetooth is not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, bluetooth

Recently I am facing an issue with bluetooth.
For last one hour I am not being able to use bluetooth. I have my bluetooth turned on but the screen is showing bluetooth turned off.

`rfkill` also shows bluetooth in the list. I have attached photos of the same.

This is what I get in `rfkill`:

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE                 SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      ideapad_wlan      unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth ideapad_bluetooth unblocked unblocked
 2 wlan      phy0              unblocked unblocked
```

This is what I get with `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` in terminal:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0901]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04f2:b628 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd EasyCamera
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

You can see in the attached photo, the bluetooth is turned on, list of devices are not showing:

[image: 1]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: just did that. Please check out.

Comment: Are you saying that Bluetooth used to work on this system, and suddenly stopped one hour ago? Or are you saying that Bluetooth has never worked on this system?

Comment: Yes. I am using bluetooth forever in this system. Now an hour back, It suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Have you rebooted your system since Bluetooth failed?

Comment: I tried few times. still the problem persists.

Comment: I don't see any BT there. But there should be one.

Comment: @Pilot6 there is `bluetooth` in `rfkill`. Any ways to fix this?

Comment: Please add `dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Comment: Did you try to reboot? If it worked before, maybe this will solve the problem.

Comment: I would say it must be a connection issue with the wifi/bt card and the motherboard or bluetooth might have got disabled in BIOS